# Relational Algebra - Intersection Properties

Tags: database, database-design, relational-algebra, set-theory

This investigation initially began with a test question, where I asserted

```
    R ∩ S = R ∩ (R ∩ S)
```

As I have researched, I have not been able to come up with much information as to the properties of intersection within relational algebra.

If this was set theory, I would assert

```
    R ∩ (R ∩ S) => Associativity
      (R ∩ R) ∩ S => Idempotence
          (R) ∩ S = R ∩ S
```

With relational algebra, we are instead operating on bags.  I believe I can take these same steps (idempotence seems trivial, and associativity is suggested on pg. 3 of http://comet.lehman.cuny.edu/stjohn/teaching/db/ullmanSlidesF00/slides7.pdf) with bags, but I cannot quite make it to a formal proof.

**Could anyone assist me in asserting (or disproving, by counterexample or otherwise) associativity and idempotence of the intersection in relational algebra?**

Thank you very much.

Comment: Relational algebra is not based on bags. Relation bodies are sets. SQL is uses bags for table bodies..

Comment: You must find/write formal definitions for the operators. The definitions will use sets/bags. Then you take the putative axiom and replace the operators by their definitions and show that that version is true. You also need a formal definition of what a relation/table is. Ie some presentations just use a set/bag but others use a heading plus (set/bag) body. What definitions of operators and relations/tables were you given?

Comment: We are using the definitions as defined in "Database Systems The Complete Book" by Garcia-Molina, Ullman, and Widom.  Honestly they're pretty vague to me, which continues to complicate matters.

Comment: Do you want to do it for sets or bags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Relational Model is formally defined over sets, so the Relational Algebra is defined only over sets. But since the Relational Databases extended the model to include multisets, or bags, the Relational Algebra has been similarly extended over multisets, and almost all the modern books on Databases describes this extension.

In particular, using the notation Op<sup>b</sup> to represent the variant of operator Op over multisets, we can define the operators ∩<sup>b</sup>, ∪<sup>b</sup> and −<sup>b</sup> as follows:

R ∩<sup>b</sup> S: if an element *t* appear *n* times in R and *m* times in S, then it appears *min(n,m)* times in R ∩<sup>b</sup> S;

R ∪<sup>b</sup> S: if an element *t* appear *n* times in R and *m* times in S, then it appears *n+m* times in R ∪<sup>b</sup> S;

R −<sup>b</sup> S: if an element *t* appear *n* times in R and *m* times in S, then it appears *max(0,n-m)* times in R −<sup>b</sup> S.

---

You want to show that:

R ∩<sup>b</sup> S = R ∩<sup>b</sup> (R ∩<sup>b</sup> S)

As your correct derivation shows, this can be proved if we can prove the Associativity and Idempotence properties for the operator ∩<sup>b</sup>.

Idempotence:

R ∩<sup>b</sup> R = R

In this case, since each element appear the same number of times in both the operands, that is *m = n*, we have that it appears *min(n, n) = n* times in the result, i.e. it appears the same number of times of R.

Associativity:

(R ∩<sup>b</sup> S) ∩<sup>b</sup> T = R ∩<sup>b</sup> (S ∩<sup>b</sup> T)

Suppose that a certain element *t* appears *n* times in R, *m* times in S, and *k* times in T, we have that in:

(R ∩<sup>b</sup> S) ∩<sup>b</sup> T

it will appear *min(min(n,m), k)* times in the result, and this is equal to *min(n,m,k)*. On the other hand, in:

R ∩<sup>b</sup> (S ∩<sup>b</sup> T)

it will appear *min(n, min(m,k))* times in the result, but this again is equal to *min(n,m,k)*.

So this means that it will appear the same number of times in both the results, and so the two results are equal.

Answer (score 0):

As philipxy has already commented, relations are sets, and therefore set theory applies.   The link provided below gives you a list of transformation equivalences, and the associative property of both union and intersection are listed in there.

http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/attachment/32495/equivalenceRules.pdf

The question might be raised about how many of the relational algebra theorems are provably true in the realm of SQL databases, rather than relational algebra.  This is problematic, because any given implementation might have bugs, and there could even be flaws in the SQL model.  I have tended to blindly assume that the results of relational algebra carry over into the practical world, but some deep thinkers sound a note of caution in that regard.